# How to get key in dictonary by values list python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

How to get key in dictonary by values list python

```
listBarang = {
"barang_1":["Rinso","K1",90,90,0,0],
"barang_2":["Molto","K4",90,90,0,0],
"barang_3":["Sunligh","K3",90,10,0,0]
}
```

Comment: Here you can find [How to Extract Key from Python Dictionary using Value](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-extract-key-from-python-dictionary-using-value-2b2f8dd2a995#:~:text=Method%201%20%3A%20Using%20List,appropriate%20key%20from%20key%20list.)

Comment: Can you be more explicit in what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Same process once you extracted the keys check keywords present or not simply using list comprehension.

```
listBarang = {
"barang_1":["Rinso","K1",90,90,0,0],
"barang_2":["Molto","K4",90,90,0,0],
"barang_3":["Sunligh","K3",90,10,0,0]
}

search_elemnt = "Sunligh"
for key in listBarang.keys():
    if search_elemnt in listBarang[key]:
        print (key)
```

**Some sample outputs**

```
search_elemnt = "Sunligh"
```

Gives #

```
barang_3
```

Sample input 2

```
search_elemnt = 90
```

Gives #

```
barang_1
barang_2
barang_3
```